When cross-compiling for an ARM embedded target using GCC, is it reasonable to expect the Windows and Linux versions to produce identical output?
I have a build for an ARM embedded target that is developed using eclipse and GCC toolchain release 12.2-rel1.
I have set up a build in TeamCity that runs in a Linux-based Docker container, also using toolchain 12.2-rel1. The build produces a significantly different sized .hex file, and the linker .map output is formatted differently.
Perhaps I'm being naive, but I expected these builds to produce identical output. Is this even a reasonable expectation? It seems like it should be when cross-compiling using same versions of the tool chain. What are possible sources of the difference?

Is every compiler optimisation setting and code generation option exactly the same?

@MartinBrown I assume so; I'm using the same Makefile. I'm not very experienced with GCC, are there some defaults set somewhere that I should check?

I'm not very experienced with gcc either but gcc -v ought to show you in detail what options are in force. Are any of the intermediate output files the same?

This is called build reproducibility.  See some points here.  For instance __LINE__ is not the same on different platforms.  I imagine that __FILE__ will be different if paths are different, etc.  Even a time maybe inserted.  There a various issues and you need to make sure the source is clear of them, before looking at the compiler itself.  Did you try to make a minimum viable difference?  Remove all linked libraries, etc.

Another good URL. https://wiki.debian.org/ReproducibleBuilds

One might expect that, but no surprise if they do not match.  There are a lot of factors and even if it is the same GNU sources there may be host differences and/or the person doing the build may have subtle build differences. I have not built on Windows for almost 20 years, but used to build on both Linux and Windows.  It would be an interesting experiment, would have been good if you had provided some simple examples of the differences.  Is it the compiler or linker or libraries?
12.2-rel does not mean much that is someones (maybe even arm's) pre-built I assume, what source they used, version of that source and compile options for that source are what matter and make big differences in the result.  What C library, where it came from, etc matter (C libraries are not part of the toolchain, they are an additional piece, part of an SDK).
There are of course compiler option differences, you are using eclipse so are you letting the IDE choose those options, vs, using the tools directly and using the same exact command lines?   Different versions of the same compiler/linker are not expected to produce the same output.  Different compile options are not expected to produce the same output.  Different compilers are not expected...
Sometimes the differences are as simple as a date will be added to the binary for various reasons making identical matches fail.  Folks or libraries the pull in may have error messages that include filename/path and line number, on the same machine, same compiler same exact options same day...different directory you will get binaries that do not match and do not match by a lot.  Back in the day with a VERY popular toolchain, whatever was in your memory at the time of build got sucked into the binary so if you had char[32]="hello";  The additional 32-6 bytes would be padded with garbage from memory, yeah, serious, so same build, same directory, same day, same files same option, etc., different binary each time.  Clearly for security reasons if nothing else the tools pad those with zeros now...
If the C library or bootstrap is different then the bootstrap itself can/will offset the entire binary causing initially everything in the map to be off by an offset, and then all alignments from there can cause different alignment based offsets to be accumulated in a different way than another build, causing further map differences.
